# Cech cohomology stays the same restrcting to a subcover?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space with an open covering $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$. Let $\mathcal{V}$ be a subcovering of $\mathcal{U}$, i.e. there exists a subset $J\subset I$ s.t. $\mathcal{V}=\{U_i\}_{i\in J}$. Then $\mathcal{V}$ refines $\mathcal{U}$ and for every sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ and all $p\geq 0$, there exists a canonical map of Cech cohomolog groups
$$H^p(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F})\to H^p(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{F}).$$

I believe this map is an isomorphism but can't think of a proof or find a reference.

The context of this question comes from [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4839612/cech-cohomology-on-infinite-open-cover-commutes-with-colimit-on-noetherian-space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true in general. For instance, let $X=S^1\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be the circle, define $U_0=S^1\setminus\{1\}$ and $U_1=S^1\setminus\{-1\}$, and let $\mathcal{U}=\{U_0, U_1, S^1\}$ and $\mathcal{V}=\{U_0, U_1\}$. Then $H^1(\mathcal{V},\mathbb{R})\cong \mathbb{R}$, while $H^1(\mathcal{U},\mathbb{R})\cong 0$ (these are mental computations, so you may want to check this).

Comment: Checked, you are right!

Comment: Though can you provide an example with Noetherian topological space? Because in my original problem the space is assumed to be Noetherian. Thanks!

Comment: I don't yet know any counterexamples in that case, also because for a qcqs scheme $X$ (even without noetherianness assumptions), the map will be an isomorphism for finite covers $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$. See e.g. Vakil's _The Rising Sea_, Theorem 18.2.2. (in the 2013 version) for this statement. Maybe the Stacks Project has more to say on this? I have to admit that I didn't really read your previous post, only this one, so sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. From the proof of the theorem, I found that if $\mathcal{V}=\mathcal{U}\backslash {U_0}$, then we can calculate $\ker(H^{p+1}(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{F})\to H^{p+1}(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{F}))=H^p(\mathcal{V}\cap U_0,\mathcal{F})$ from a short exact sequence of complexes. So if we pick $U_0=X,p=0,\mathcal{F}=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ then $H^0(\mathcal{V}\cap U_0,\mathcal{F})=H^0(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}(X)=\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(X)\neq 0$. Thus the above map is almost never true unless $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ is carefully chosen (e.g. affine).